# How to extract part of item in a list using slice?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have the following list:

```
item = [['01jan.jpg', 'Cluny', 'Tres Riches Heures', 'January'],
        ['02feb.jpg', 'Cluny', 'Tres Riches Heures', 'February']]
```

and want to extract the first entry and change the `.jpg` to `.png`:

```
x = item[0][0]    print(x)  # gives '01jan.jpg'
y = slice(x[:-4]) print(y)  # gives 'slice(None, '01jan', None)'
```

and I can't get the middle term out because slice object is not iterable.
How do I get `'01jan'` as a variable?  Other items have varying names but all have the same `.jpg` so I want to slice off the back of the first item.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with just running `x[:-4]` without `slice`? That will get you `01jan`. The other way of doing it is `x[slice(-4)]` but nobody uses this notation.